# Show independence of $(aX,bX^2)$, $\,X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$?

Tags: probability-theory

How can we proof that $aX,bX^2$ are independent iff $b\cdot a=0$, when $\,X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$?

I found that $X^2$ is Chi-Square distributed, and the correlation is:

$$\rho(bX,aX^2)=ba\rho(X,X^2)=ba\dfrac{\mathrm{Cov}(X,X^2)}{ \sigma_X \sigma_{X^2}} =ba\dfrac{E[(X-\mu_X)(X^2-\mu_{X^2})]}{ \sigma_X\sigma_{X^2}}\stackrel{!}{=}0$$
So we have $\rho=0$ when $ba=0$, but as we know, $\rho=0$ does not directly imply independence in general. We may need to argue why it does here, or use some other dependence measure to show independence.

Comment: Have you tried going directly from the definition, i.e. the variables are independent if $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, and showing that it is true implies either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$?

Comment: This could also be a solution, but I think its much more complicated because we would need to find the joint distribution for this.

Comment: @emcor: If $U$ is any random variable, and $V$ is a.e. constant, then $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks thats correct, could you send your answer with an appropriate source/theorem (I would need it)? Then I can also give you full score ;)

Comment: Hmmm... by the way, if $X$ is centered normal, then $\rho(X,X^2)=0$ hence $\rho(bX,aX^2)=0$, always. Thus, the proof in this question, that [independence $\implies ab=0$], is flawed. (Rather amazing to see such blunders go unnoticed by the several users who got interested in the question at the time, including those who answered it. Actually one even fails to see how the accepted answer addresses the question at all (the other answer at least does, partly).)

Comment: @emcor Not interested in cleaning the mess on this page?

Comment: The new version might be even *less* understandable.

Comment: @Did I am not sure if you can directly say $\rho(X,X^2)=0$ here because how can you justify (as it seems) $E(\cdot)=E(\cdot)E(\cdot)$? Note that $X^2$ is Chi-Square distributed so the expectation might be something different?

Comment: *Think!* And no, there is no general argument to say that $E(X\cdot X^2)=E(X)\cdot E(X^2)$ always. But in the present case...

Comment: @Did Ok we have $\mu_X=0$ and $\mu_X^2=0$ but then $E(X^3)=2\sigma^2>0$?

Comment: this would go along with the idea that its only independent iff $ba=0$.

Comment: No, $E(X^3)$ is not $2\sigma^2$ (where did you get the idea?).

Comment: @Did https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments Ok it would be $2\sigma^3$ but still $>0$.

Comment: No, $E(X^3)$ is not $2\sigma^3$. (Sorry but I will not be able to continue like this much longer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be any random variable, and let $V$ be equal to $k$ with probability $1$. Then $U$ and $V$ are independent.

There are two cases. (i) Suppose that $k\not\in B$. Then $\Pr((U\in A) \cap (V\in B))=0$. This is equal to $\Pr(U\in A)\Pr(V\in B)$, since $\Pr(V\in B)=0$.  (ii) Suppose that $k\in B$. Then  $\Pr((U\in A) \cap (V\in B))=\Pr(U\in A)$. This is $\Pr(U\in A)\Pr(V\in B)$, since $\Pr(V\in B)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Sufficient condition is trival, since any constant is indepedent of any random variable. For the necessary condition, we can do something as following.

Suppose that $ab \neq 0$. Without loss of generality, we can only consider the cases that $a, b$ are both positive. (For other cases, the proofs are similar.) We plan to show that $aX$ and $bX^2$ are not independent.

Suppose they are independent. For any two (Borel) sets $A$ and $B$, we have $\mathrm{Pr}(aX\in A, bX^2 \in B) = \mathrm{Pr}(aX \in A)\mathrm{Pr}(bX^2 \in B)$. Now consider following two special cases for $A$ and $B$:

$$
A := \{x | -\delta_1 < x < \delta_1 \} \\
B := \{x | 0 \leq x < \delta_2 \}
$$
where $\delta_1, \delta_2 > 0$ and $\frac{\delta_1^2}{a^2} = \frac{\delta_2}{b}$. It's easy to check that $aX\in A$ if and only if $bX^2\in B$. Note that $0<\mathrm{Pr}(aX\in A) = \mathrm{Pr}(bX^2 \in B) < 1$. Therefore, we have

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(aX\in A, bX^2 \in B) = \mathrm{Pr}(aX\in A) > \mathrm{Pr}(aX \in A)\mathrm{Pr}(bX^2 \in B)
$$

The necessarity is followed by contradiction.

Comment: Thanks but we already know that for $ab\neq0$ they are not independent, since the correlation would be nonzero (so some linear dependence) as shown in my question. For $ab=0$, we have from AndreNicolas that at least $aX=0$ or $bX^2=0$ so one of them is constant and they must be independent.